# How to get the current page name in Silex

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

I'm wondering how to get the current page name, basically 'just' the last parameter in the route (i.e. /news or /about). I'm doing this because I want to be able to have the current page in the navigation highlighted.

Ideally, I'd like to store the current page name in a global variable so that in Twig I can just compare the current page name against the link and add a class accordingly.

I can't figure out how to add the current page name to a global variable though. I've tried using something like this:

```
$app['twig']->addGlobal('current_page_name', $app['request']->getRequestUri());
```

at the top of my app.php file, but an 'outside of request scope' error. But I wouldn't like to have to include this in every route.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you put it into an app-level before middleware like this, that'll work:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $app['twig']->addGlobal('current_page_name', $request->getRequestUri());
});
```

The "page name" part of your question is unclear, are you looking for the current route's name? You can access that via `$request->get("_route")` even in the before middleware, as it gets called when routing is already done.

Comment: Thanks, works great! I updated my question to better explain what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You could also generate navigation list directly in stand alone nav twig template. And then import it in to the main template. Then you would only have to get silex to pass to the view the current page identifier. Simplest way... for example from Silex you would have to pass in the "path" variable to your view. Probably it would more convenient to  to fetch nav_list from database and pass it in to twig template as global array variable instead. However this example is the simplest you could get to do what you intend.

nav.twig

```
{% set nav_list = [
  ["./",        "home"],
  ["./contact", "contact"],
  ["./about",   "about us"]
  {# ... #}
] %}

{% set link_active = path|default("") %}

{% for link in nav_list %}
  <li><a href="{{ link[0] }}" class="{% if link[0] == link_active %} activeClass {% endif %}" >{{ link[1] }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

app.php

```
//...
    $app->match('/about', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
        return $app['twig']->render('about.twig', array(
            'path' => './'.end(explode('/', $request->getRequestUri()))
        ));
    });
//...
```